# How do I preserve DIRECTORY file mode or permission in git?

Tags: git, directory, file-permissions, directory-permissions

We have a remote git repo and some time we create directories with permission 777 but when others pull from the remote repo and checkout, directory permission isn't 777. How can I preserve directory permission in git?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git` does not track permissions on files (only a single flag for executable/not executable), and does not track directories at all. If you really need to propagate permissions, you can add a short script to your repository that will set appropriate permissions, or research `git` add-on tools that essentially do this for you by capturing file metadata and re-implementing it on the remote end.

Comment: Thanks, do you know some of those add-on tools?

Comment: The wiki at https://git.wiki.kernel.org has a list of additional tools, several of which are for maintaining metadata.

Comment: Just a somewhat related note in case it helps anyone. Working in Linux with a directory that is actually a symlink to a Windows folder (easy to forget) will cause Git to even ignore changes to executable permissions within that folder. Best to have native Linux for Git repos where permissions matter.